# What is happening to old classes?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class ContentConfigParser(object):
    def __init__(self,txt):
        try:
            with open (txt,'r') as conf:
                conflines = conf.readlines()
                self.width = conflines[0].strip()
                self.height = conflines[1].strip()
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
while 1:
    config= ContentConfigParser("settings.txt") #1
    #bla bla with config.width
    #peh peh with config.height
```

What is happening to the old classes that I used at (1) ?
Is it a good coding?

Comment: Unused instances of your class will be released from memory. Concerning the logic: I don't see why you have to recreate an instance of the `ContentConfigParser` again and again in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your attantion. How can i re-read the file to get settings again and again? Devesh Kumar Singh gives an alternate for that, did you mentioning a solution like it?

Comment: Yes, you can re-run the `openfile` function to read the file again, and set the `width` and `height` attribute again! Check my answer below @HakanUlusoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have at 1 aren't classes but objects or instances. They will get discarded (or marked for the garbage collector to pick up) once they have no reference remaining/go out of scope. So they'll get removed each iteration. The question is if you can't create the instance outside of the loop and then keep using it inside of it.